# how to know the entangled state is changed?

Tags: entanglement

Alice and Bob share a bell state (1). now suppose Alice perform an X gate on her qubit.

then the entangled state will convert to state (2) as follow

[image]

does Bob realize what Alice did? does he realize what is the new state?

Comment: please see https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/tutorial-how-to-use-tex-mathjax-to-render-math-notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Bob will not be able to tell what Alice if he only looks at his part of the state. You can see this by computing Bob's reduced density matrix by tracing over Alice's degree of freedom; the result, in both cases, is $$\rho_B=\frac{|0\rangle\langle 0|+|1\rangle\langle 1|}{2}.$$